# Django 1.10.6 - MP3 Upload and player

Tags: python, html, django

For a job interview I need to code a website consisting of at least 3 pages for a fictional band's website using Django.

My idea is to:

- have a front page with blog posts from the band, the most recent one on top.
- have an admin page where I can upload the band's songs.
- have a page with a list of songs that can be played by clicking on the song.

I know very basic html and css (did some one codecademy).
I did the Django tutorial up until part 6 https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/intro/tutorial06/

I'm just not very sure how to go about doing this. (Would I use "static files" for the mp3's? How does one set up a blog format page?)

So I'm just hoping for a nudge in the right direction. Any links to tutorials or books or anything that might be useful would be much appreciated.

Comment: generally use audio, video files as media files. So you can startwith fileupload. https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.FileField

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe this tutorial would be helpful for this project https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qgGIqRFvFFk&list=PL6gx4Cwl9DGBlmzzFcLgDhKTTfNLfX1IK